# Watching in vue cann't work in some case

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I used transition in vue by watching current value in vuex using 'alertTip' component to achieve fade-in and fade-out animation, but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work. When value changed and the function in watch doesn't work, the 'tips' can't disappear and shows all the time.

How to resolve this problem?
If there has other method to achieve fade-in and fade-out animation without jQuery.

Here is the code of the 'alertTip' component:

```
<template>
  <transition name="slide-fade">
    <div class="info-log" v-if="alertInfo.show">
      <img src="../assets/success-icon.png" alt="success-icon" v-if="alertInfo.success">
      <img src="../assets/error-icon.png" alt="success-icon" v-else>
      <span class="info-text">{{alertInfo.alertText}}</span>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>


<script>
  import {mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        value: ''
      }
    },
    props: [],
    mounted () {

    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions('global', [
        '_ChangeAlertInfo'
      ]),
      showTip () {
        let self = this
        this.show = !this.show
        setTimeout(function () {
          self.show = !self.show
        }, 1300)
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters('global', [
        'alertInfo'
      ])
    },
    watch: {
      'alertInfo.show': {
        deep: true,
        handler (curVal, oldVal) {
          let self = this
          setTimeout(function () {
            self._ChangeAlertInfo({
              'show': false
            })
          }, 1300)
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>


<style lang="less" scoped>
  .slide-fade-enter-active {
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }
  .slide-fade-leave-active {
    transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
  }
  .slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .info-log {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1111;
    margin-left: -92px;
    min-width: 184px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    /* IE8 */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7f000000,endColorstr=#7f000000);
    .info-text {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: When to use `showTip` method? It looks not used anywhere in that component. This component is aimed to be used to show tips by changing the value in vuex in another component?

Comment: alertInfo is stored in vuex, when properties in alertInfo changes, this component will show and disappear by watching 'alertInfo.show'

Comment: the method of showing the tips:   this._ChangeAlertInfo({
                                                            'alertText': error.msg,
                                                            'show': true,
                                                            'success': false
                                                      })

Comment: Could you append the content of `_ChangeAlertInfo` as well? That would be a clue.